# What does external linkage mean

Tags: c++, extern, linkage

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace EnclosingNmspc
{
    namespace Nmspc
    {
        extern int a;//This a and the a defined above denote the same entity
        int a=5;
    }
}

extern int a;

int main()
{ 
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

There is the quote from 3.5/2:

> When a name has external linkage , the entity it denotes can be
>   referred to by names from scopes of other translation units or from
>   other scopes of the same translation unit.

I dont understand why this rule doesn't work in my case? I have `undefined reference` linker error.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is already answered [there canonically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).

You've been missing to have a definition for `::a` in a different compilation unit.

`int a=5;` actually defines `extern int a;` in the same scope. But that's not accessed with

```
printf("%d\n",a);
```

in your main program. To check for the stuff from your namespace try

```
printf("%d\n",EnclosingNmspc::Nmspc::a);
```

Comment: But the spec said that _the entity it denotes can be referred to by names from scopes of other translation units or `from other scopes of the same translation unit`._

Comment: @St.Antario you still have to provide a definition, the compiler doesn't do it for you automatically.

Comment: It's either declare `extern int a;` and have the definition elsewhere, **or** define `int a;` and have it accessible from elsewhere through an `extern` declaration. If you want to hide `a` from external linkage put it in an unnamed namespace.

Comment: Note that there is no shadowing (see 3.3.10/1). Declaration extern int a and definition int a=5 denote the same entity (see 3.3.1/4).

Comment: What should be the point of using `extern` there then??

Comment: @St.Antario Look at `extern` like a forward declaration. `void f();` and `void f() {}` denote the same entity too.

Comment: The point is to understand what does quote in my start post mean? I'm trying to do an example that explain how does external linkage works for names located in the same translation unit.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious It is not depends on extern specifier. I don't understand what you tried to say in your comment?