# C scope and extern usage

Tags: c

I have this source of a single file that is successfully compiled in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a;
unsigned char b = 'A';
extern int alpha;

int main() {
    extern unsigned char b;
    double a = 3.4;
    {
        extern a;

        printf("%d %d\n", b, a+1);

   } 
return 0;
}
```

After running it, the output is

> 65 1

Could anybody please tell me why the extern a statement will capture the global value instead of the **double** local one and why the **printf** statement print the global value instead of the local one?

Also, I have noticed that if I change the statement on line 3 from

```
int a;
```

to

```
int a2;
```

I will get an error from the **extern a;** statement. Why does not a just use the assignment **double a=3.4;** ? It's not like it is bound to be int.

Comment: Check here please: [What does external linkage mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846057/what-does-external-linkage-mean/23846114#23846114), and of course [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: That wouldn't even compile in C++. Maybe you should remove that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's not like it is bound to be int.

Actually, it is. In the declaration

```
extern a;
```

The (implicit) type of `a` is indeed `int`. Declarations in C without any specific type always default to `int`.

In addition, an `extern` declaration cannot refer to a local variable (even one declared within the same function).

Comment: By local you mean a variable declared in any block, accessible or not from the current one, right?

Comment: @user2565010: Yes, an `extern` declaration can only refer to another global declaration, essentially.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot for the information. I can see now the situation in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
extern a;
```

shadows the previous declaration. Until the scope where this is declared ends, this declaration takes precedence over the definition

```
double a = 3.4;
```